# Proper naming of folder, namespace and class for big projects

Tags: c#, class, namespaces, structure

I'm trying to create a artificial brain for my experiment, and I know this will become really big, because brain contain 4 structures and every structures contain mini-structures and so on... So to organize my brain I need a proper and correct naming of folder, namespace and class.

OK, Let's say I have an object named `Brain` inside the brain I have another object or structure named `Cerebrum`, `Cerebellum`, `Limbic` and `Stem`.

What I currently have is: `[Folder]>Class.cs`

For Example:

```
 - [Brain]
  - [Cerebrum]
     - Cerebrum.cs
  - [Cerebellum]
     - [Folder etc..]
         - Etc.cs
     - Cerebellum.cs
  - [Limbic]
  - [Stem]
  - Brain.cs
```

[image: Brain Project]

So when I Include them in other class.

```
using App.Brain;
using App.Brain.Cerebrum;
```

But the problem here is, when you create a Instantiate of the class you always need to type the namespace `Brain` to show `Brain` object even if you already declare it by `using App.Brain;`.

```
Brain.Brain AI = new Brain.Brain();
Brain.Cerebrum.Cerebrum AICerebrum = new Brain.Cerebrum.Cerebrum();
```

Can you give my any suggestion to fix my structures?

Comment: Maybe you could rename your top level namespace to HumanBrain?

Comment: @JasonNesbitt Hmn, So I also need to rename the other namespace to `'BrainCerebrum'` and `'CerebrumEtc'` and so on?

Comment: No, only Brain to HumanBrain, if I'm understanding you correctly.  Your problem is that you have a type and a namespace with the same name.  Brain is the only place where I see that as an issue.

Comment: @JasonNesbitt Oh,I'm Sorry I forgot to type `Brain.Cerebrum.Cerebrum`

Comment: I see.  Yes, this can be tricky sometimes, but I think the right solution depends on the context.  Often you have more wiggle room with the namespace.  For starters, it sounds a bit odd that something falls under a Cerebrum but is also next to a Cerebrum.  Maybe remove the Cerebrum namespace, make it a class under Brain (or HumanBrain) and the classes that make up the Cerebrum would be inner classes that fall inside of Cerebrum.cs?

Comment: That makes more sense if only the top level Cerebrum class needs to interact with those parts.  Another option would be to put Cerebrum.cs under HumanBrain and create a folder/namespace CerebrumParts under HumanBrain.

Comment: @JasonNesbitt I love your Idea. So It will become classes in class in namespace in folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64831/discussion-between-leonel-and-jason-nesbitt).

Comment: Fantastic example you used

Comment: Naming namespaces, classes and properties the same will only cause you pain (like `Brain.Brain.Brain`). Unfortunately decision if you need to do so or not is very personal and is outside of scope for SO.